# What is the correct way to allocate memory for an array depending on a command line parameter?

Tags: c, arrays, memory

When writing a program in which I ask the user to enter number N, which I have to use to allocate the memory for an `int` array, what is the correct way to handle this:

**First approach:**

```
int main() {
  int array[],n;
  scanf("%d\n",&n);
  array = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
}
```

**or the second approach:**

```
int main() {
  int n;
  scanf("%d\n",&n);
  int array[n];
}
```

Comment: My C standard knowledge seems to be rusty, do any of those attempts  even compile?

Comment: Both don't get it from the command line, however, the first one is illegal as the array size is missing.

Comment: This examples might be oversimplified. Considering portability, should I then always allocate array with some fixed N before getting N from the user using `scanf()`?

Comment: both heap and stack variables have their advantages: http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html

Comment: Not in main, with c99 you can allocate it on the stack and most compilers will do it in ansi c unless you are in pedantic mode ... Still it's always fine to use malloc.  It's too tempting to do this in a function and expect it to be there when it returns.

Comment: Let me propose `calloc` being superior to `malloc` as it initializes all elements to `zero` (null). This can prevent uninitialized elements causing problem if the array is filled/accessed in random order.

Answer (score 4):

Either one will work (though the first case needs to be changed from `int array[]` to `int *array`); the difference depends on where the array is stored.

In the first case, the array will be stored in the heap, while in the second case, it'll (most likely) be stored on the stack. When it's stored on the stack, the maximum size of the array will be much more limited based on the limit of the stack size. If it's stored in the heap, however, it can be much larger.

Comment: I also prefer the first case because it makes the dynamic nature of the memory more clear. Two brackets tacked on the end get lost in the other code words.

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach is called a variable length array (VLA), and is supported only as of c99. This means that if you intend your code to be compatible with older compilers (or to be read and understood by older people..), you may have to fall back to the first option which is more standard. Note that dynamically allocating data requires proper maintenance, the most important part of that being - freeing it when you're done (which you don't do in your program)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant to use `int *array;` instead of `int array[];`(The first one wouldn't compile).

Always use the first approach unless you know the array size is going to be very small *and* you have the intimate knowledge of the platforms your will be running on. Naturally, the question arises how small is small enough?

The main problem with second approach is that there's no portable way to verify whether the VLA (Varible Length Array) allocation succeeded. The advantage is that you don't have to manage the memory but that's hardly an "advantage" considering the risk of *undefined behaviour* in case memory allocation fails.

It was introduced in C99 and been **made optional in C11**. That suggests the committee found it not-so-useful. Also, C11 compilers may not support it and you have to perform additional check whether your compiler supports it or not by checking if `__STDC_NO_VLA__` has been defined.

Automatic storage allocation for an array as small `int my_arr[10];` could fail. This is an extreme and unrealistic example in modern operating systems, but possible in theory. So I suggest to avoid VLAs in any serious projects.

Answer (score 0):

You did say you wanted a COMMAND LINE parameter:

```
  int main (int argc, char **argv)
  {
     int *array ;
     int count ;
     if (argc < 2)
       return 1 ;
     count = atoi (argv[1]) ;
     array = malloc (sizeof(int)*count) ;

     . . .  . . 

     free (array) ;
     return 0 ;
  }
```